# Index match match to find start and end time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a dataset where I want to find the name and last name based on the user id. I already accomplish this part. As a next step, with the same user id, I have to find the start and end time of a schedule based on a given date.

The data looks as follows:

[image: image of data set]

Currently I am using the following formula which ends with a `#N/A` error.

```
=INDEX(A2:Q28,MATCH(C12,A2:Q2,0),MATCH(F9&F10,D$1:Q$1&D$2:Q$2,0))
```

Comment: I would break out the individual `MATCH` formulas from your overall formula to see if in fact it is returning numbers. Another thing to think about is how to handle situations where there is no match.

Comment: According to your sample, the formula seems to be `==INDEX($D$11:$Q$13,MATCH($A4,$A$11:$A$13,0),MATCH(F9&F10,$D$2:$Q$2&$D$3:$Q$3,0))`.